# Как это перевети на использование библиотеки JACKSON?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Сейчас используется библиотека GSON, хочу перейти на использование JSON при помощи библиотеки JACKSON (хотя бы попробовать, слышал, что работает быстрее). Для работы с датами и ByteArray создана такая обложка:

```
public class MyGsonWrapper
{
public static Gson getMyGson()
{
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateSerializer());
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new GsonDateDeserializer());

    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, new GsonByteArraySerializer());

    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

static class GsonDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String s = json.getAsString().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;
        ...........
        if (isDateBefore1970)
            return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
        else
            return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

    }
}

static class GsonDateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }
}

static class GsonByteArraySerializer implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>
{
    public JsonElement serialize(byte[] data, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeBytes(data));
    }
}
}
```

С ByteArray JACKSON работает и сам нормально, следовательно GsonByteArraySerializer не нужен, с датами в миллисекунды тоже там настраивается и он сам работает с ними, как я понимаю. Может я в чем то не прав? Помогите переделать, что бы перейти с GSON на JACKSON библиотеку. Как я понимаю, новая обвертка должна начинаться так:

```
 public class MyJsonWrapper     {

public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

    module.addSerializer(byte[].class, new JsonByteArraySerializer());

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>
{

    public Date deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws java.io.IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {

    }

static class JsonDateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public JsonParser serialize(Date date, Type typeOfT, Serializers context)
    {
        return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }
}

static class JsonByteArraySerializer implements JsonSerializer<byte[]>
{
    public JsonParser serialize(byte[] data, Type typeOfT, Serializers context)
    {
        return new JsonPrimitive(Base64.encodeBytes(data));
    }
}
```

Раньше сериализация и десериализация проходили следующим образом:

MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().toJson(MyObject)
MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().fromJson(response.Body, MyObject[].class);

Может эта обвертка и не нужна совсем, может на прямую обращаться к функциям JACKSON?
Если она все таки нужна, подскажите как изменить. Если не нужна, то через какие какие именно функции из библиотеки осуществлять сериализация и десериализация и как к ним обращаться...

Comment: Не Jackson, а JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyJacksonWrapper
{
public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS, false);

    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{

    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        String s = jp.getText().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;
        .............
        if (isDateBefore1970)
            return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
        else
            return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

    }
}

static class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }

}
}
```